# Glassfish 5, Grave: Exception during lifecycle processing org.glassfish.deployment.common.DeploymentException

Tags: java-8, jersey, glassfish, glassfish-5

he tried to start a jsf application on a glassfish 5.0 server with java 8, but now I try to start the program and this error occurs, I have tried several things even adding some jersey libraries. I do not understand why this error occurs to me, the truth is that I have searched a lot through internet, but nothing has worked for me so far

```
        Grave:   Exception during lifecycle processing
        org.glassfish.deployment.common.DeploymentException: CDI deployment failure:Error while loading class com.sun.jersey.guice.spi.container.servlet.GuiceContainer
            at org.glassfish.weld.WeldDeployer.event(WeldDeployer.java:239)
            at org.glassfish.kernel.event.EventsImpl.send(EventsImpl.java:131)
            at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.load(ApplicationInfo.java:328)
            at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:496)
            at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
            at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491)
            at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:540)
            at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:536)
            at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
            at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
            at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:535)
            at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:566)
            at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:558)
            at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
            at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
            at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:557)
            at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1465)
            at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:110)
            at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1847)
            at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1723)
            at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:534)
            at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:224)
            at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandlerBase.service(StaticHttpHandlerBase.java:190)
            at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:463)
            at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:168)
            at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
            at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
            at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:242)
            at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
            at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
            at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
            at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
            at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
            at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
            at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:539)
            at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
            at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
            at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
            at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
            at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:593)
            at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:573)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
        Caused by: org.jboss.weld.resources.spi.ResourceLoadingException: Error while loading class com.sun.jersey.guice.spi.container.servlet.GuiceContainer
            at org.jboss.weld.resources.ClassTransformer.getBackedAnnotatedType(ClassTransformer.java:183)
            at org.jboss.weld.resources.ClassTransformer.getBackedAnnotatedType(ClassTransformer.java:191)
            at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.createAnnotatedType(BeanManagerImpl.java:1118)
            at org.glassfish.weld.WeldDeployer.firePITEvent(WeldDeployer.java:403)
            at org.glassfish.weld.WeldDeployer.fireProcessInjectionTargetEvents(WeldDeployer.java:374)
            at org.glassfish.weld.WeldDeployer.event(WeldDeployer.java:226)
            ... 41 more

    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/inject/Injector
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2671)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2020)
        at org.jboss.weld.annotated.slim.backed.SecurityActions.getDeclaredConstructors(SecurityActions.java:57)
    at org.jboss.weld.annotated.slim.backed.BackedAnnotatedType$BackedAnnotatedConstructors.computeValue(BackedAnnotatedType.java:166)
    at org.jboss.weld.annotated.slim.backed.BackedAnnotatedType$BackedAnnotatedConstructors.computeValue(BackedAnnotatedType.java:163)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.LazyValueHolder.get(LazyValueHolder.java:46)
    at org.jboss.weld.annotated.slim.backed.BackedAnnotatedType$EagerlyInitializedLazyValueHolder.<init>(BackedAnnotatedType.java:159)
    at org.jboss.weld.annotated.slim.backed.BackedAnnotatedType$BackedAnnotatedConstructors.<init>(BackedAnnotatedType.java:163)
    at org.jboss.weld.annotated.slim.backed.BackedAnnotatedType$BackedAnnotatedConstructors.<init>(BackedAnnotatedType.java:163)
    at org.jboss.weld.annotated.slim.backed.BackedAnnotatedType.<init>(BackedAnnotatedType.java:64)
    at org.jboss.weld.annotated.slim.backed.BackedAnnotatedType.of(BackedAnnotatedType.java:47)
    at org.jboss.weld.resources.ClassTransformer$TransformClassToBackedAnnotatedType.apply(ClassTransformer.java:81)
    at org.jboss.weld.resources.ClassTransformer$TransformClassToBackedAnnotatedType.apply(ClassTransformer.java:76)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.cache.ReentrantMapBackedComputingCache.lambda$null$0(ReentrantMapBackedComputingCache.java:55)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.WeakLazyValueHolder$1.computeValue(WeakLazyValueHolder.java:35)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.WeakLazyValueHolder.get(WeakLazyValueHolder.java:53)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.cache.ReentrantMapBackedComputingCache.getValue(ReentrantMapBackedComputingCache.java:72)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.cache.ReentrantMapBackedComputingCache.getCastValue(ReentrantMapBackedComputingCache.java:78)
    at org.jboss.weld.resources.ClassTransformer.getBackedAnnotatedType(ClassTransformer.java:174)
    ... 46 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.inject.Injector
    at com.sun.enterprise.loader.ASURLClassLoader.findClassData(ASURLClassLoader.java:833)
    at com.sun.enterprise.loader.ASURLClassLoader.findClass(ASURLClassLoader.java:742)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 66 more
```

I tried adding the libraries
jersey-gf-server.jar, and in the application add that same library

my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <!--<filter>
        <filter-name>guiceFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>-->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Production</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>facelets.DEVELOPMENT</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.DATETIMECONVERTER_DEFAULT_TIMEZONE_IS_SYSTEM_TIMEZONE</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
        <param-value>bootstrap</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>ServletAdaptor</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <description>Multiple packages, separated by semicolon(;), can be specified in param-value</description>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.rastrack.webServices</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponseFilters</param-name>
            <param-value>com.rastrack.filters.CORSResponseFilter</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ServletAdaptor</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/restful_api/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            120
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>faces/login.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>Primefaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>Primefaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: It seems you're using Guice as injector framework and this cannot be found `Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/inject/Injector`

Comment: How do I remove guice as an injector? or how do I make him find it?